# Unexpected behavior using Multiprocessing.Pool inside for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, pool

Here's my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def foo(p):
    global i
    return p*i

global lower, upper
lower = 1
upper = 4

for i in range(lower, upper):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        dataset = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
        agents = mp.cpu_count() - 1
        chunksize = 5
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=agents)
        result = pool.map(foo, dataset, chunksize)
        print result
        print i
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The console prints out the array [3, 6, 9,...,300] three times with the integers 1,2,3 in-between each array printout.  So i is correctly iterating between lower & upper (not inclusive), but I expected it to print out the array [1, 2, 3,...,100] first followed by [2, 4, 6,...,200] and finally [3, 6, 9,...,300]. I don't understand why it's only passing the final value of i to foo and then mapping that thrice.

Comment: Is this on Windows? Or a UNIX-alike? Makes a big difference in how the child processes are created (your behavior is expected, if confusing, on Windows).

Comment: Yes on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the new process, this is what it sees:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def foo(p):
    global i
    return p*i

global lower, upper
lower = 1
upper = 4

for i in range(lower, upper):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # This part is not run, as
        # in a different process,
        # __name__ is set to '__mp_main__'
# i is now `upper - 1`, call `foo(p)` with the provided `p`
```

And after executing that, it is told to run `foo` (It has to run the whole script again to find out what `foo` is, just because of how pickling it works)

So, after it runs that, `i` will be `upper - 1`, and it will return `p * 3` always.

You want to make `i` a parameter given to `foo`, or some multiprocessing specific memory sharing object, as descibed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: Note: This is the case on Windows, or if you explicitly opted into the `'spawn'` start method on another OS. On a UNIX-like system (e.g. Linux, BSD), the default start method `'fork'` will, under this design, properly set `i` (because the value of `i` is reflected in the fork that occurs when you create each `Pool`).

Comment: @ Artyer - So nothing inside the 'if __name__ = '__main__' conditional is initially run...it just loops through the iterable and then i is left at upper-1.  Then it runs the code inside the aforementioned conditional with the same value of i.  But it does so exactly len(range) # of times?  If this is the case, then shouldn't the value of i that gets printed out inside the "if __name__..." conditional also equal 3 all three times it prints out?  Why is it printing out 1,2,3 for i?  Is it because I'm using global i in foo (which is set to 3) but printing out 'local' values of i inside the loop?

Comment: @F.F. In the new process, `i` will always be `3` (It runs the entire thing again). In the old process, `i` is unchanged (as it is a seperate `i`).

Answer (score 1):

Make i local and using functools.partial may solve your problem:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import functools

def foo(p,i):
    return p*i

global lower, upper
lower = 1
upper = 4

for i in range(lower, upper):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        dataset = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
        agents = mp.cpu_count() - 1
        chunksize = 5
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=agents)
        foo2 = functools.partial(foo, i)
        result = pool.map(foo2, dataset, chunksize)
        print(result)
        print(i)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```